# NSTimer run every minute but on first second

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have experience with NSTimer to run it once per minute, like

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60.0, target: self, selector: Selector("everyMinute"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Is it possible to use NSTimer, some other class, or some other control, to run some method every minute but on first second of minute ?

I do have some idea how to implement it on my own, but I am first checking is this already exist ?

Comment: Any particular reason you need the first second of every minute as opposed to just once a minute? Just asking because it's very unlikely that the time on the current device you are running on will be exactly correct.

Comment: I think the question is, is there anyway we could guarantee the execution of something at exactly the time we want based on the time of the device. Would like to know this myself as well.

Comment: @Fogmeister I want to update minutes on custom label, but want it to be correct in -+2 seconds. But do not want to call NSTimer every second. I know it is crazy :-)

Comment: @Unheilig you understand it correctly

Comment: I need to correctly understand the question. If it's 7:03:35s you want the timer to fire at 7:04:01, 7:05:01 and 7:xx:01 ... ?

Comment: @LastMove yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way would be to figure out the current next minute using an NSCalendar and schedule the timer to start from that, manually scheduling on the runLoop

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitEra|NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
components.minute += 1
components.second = 1
let nextMinuteDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: nextMinuteDate!, interval: 60, target: self, selector: Selector("everyMinute"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
```

Comment: I like your approach, I had same idea, but my code would end up more complicated.

Comment: I guess you also might set `components.second = 0`, I don't think you actually need it to be on the first second

Comment: Very nice way! And yes components.second = 0 is better.

Answer (score 5):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232733/1317564), updated for Swift 5:

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
var components = calendar.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date)

guard let minute = components.minute else { return }
components.second = 0
components.minute = minute + 1

guard let nextMinute = calendar.date(from: components) else { return }

let timer = Timer(fire: nextMinute, interval: 60, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
    self?.everyMinute()
}
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .default)
```

Answer (score 1):

The NSDate method timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate returns the number of seconds since January 1, 2001, at 12:00 a.m. GMT. It includes fractions of a second

If you call that, divide by 60, take the floor value, then multiply by 60, it should  give you the time interval of the current "round minute". Add 60 to that, and you get the time interval for the next "round minute. Add 1 to THAT, and you get a time interval for one second after the next "round minute".

The code might look something like this:

```
NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval nextMinute = floor(now/60)*60 + 61 //time interval for next minute, plus 1 second
NSTimeInterval delay = nextMinute - now;
//Delay now contains the number of seconds until the next "round minute", plus 1 second.

dispatch_after(
  dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
  (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), 
  dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
  {
    //Replace the code below with whatever target/userInfo you need.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60
      target: self
      userInfo: nil;
      repeats: YES];
  }
);
```

Edit: Actually, the "First second" of a minute is the zero'th second, so you should probably change the +61 in the code above that calculated `nextMinute` to "+60", not "+61"

Comment: Your logic is same as Fabio answer, are the some difference ?

Comment: My solution uses purely arithmetic. Fabio's requires the use of NSCalendar and NSDateComponents.

Comment: let delay = 60 - NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() % 60

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach:

```
func everyMinute() {
  // some code you want done every minute, in the first second, or VERY close to it
  let delaySeconds = 60 - NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)
  Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delaySeconds, repeats: false) { timer in 
     self.everyMinute()
  }
}
```