# NSTimer run every 30 seconds but always fire on xx:00sec or xx:30sec of a minute

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have a question similar to : [NSTimer run every minute but on first second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232131/nstimer-run-every-minute-but-on-first-second)

I want the timer to start the next first second of the minute or the next half of the minute. Let's say the current time is : `12min:34sec` the next desired fire time will be `13min:00sec` , and if it's `12min:15sec` it should fire `12min:30sec`.

basically I need to fire on each `xx:00sec` and `xx:30sec` of each minute.

this is the code that fires each first second: I need to find the right component for minutes and seconds

```
    let currentCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Era, .Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute]
    let components = currentCalendar.components(unitFlags , fromDate: NSDate())
    components.minute += 1
    components.second = 0

    let nextMinuteDate = currentCalendar.dateFromComponents(components)

    let reloadTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(kReloadDataTimeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(loadData) , userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    reloadTimer.fireDate = nextMinuteDate!
```

Comment: Paste your code...

Comment: Why not firing the method (the one you pass in its selector), then fire the NSTimer according to your needs (30s or 0s of each minutes)?

Comment: Ok, and whats the issue? What have you tried and whats not working? wheres your code? what error messages are you getting?

Comment: Create a timer with interval `30 - (seconds-of-current-date % 30)`. Then on the first fire date set the interval to `30.0`

Comment: @AmitKalghatgi code pasted

Comment: @Larme that's what I did, I have removed the requirement to fire the first time as soon as possible, but  ineed to fire each 30 sec BUT starting from next first second OR next XXm:30s

Comment: @vadian your answer is the closest to solution, do you mind posting an answer and I will accept it with a code example

Answer (score 3):

- Create a `NSTimer` property

  ```
  var timer : NSTimer!
  ```
- initialize the property in a method using a non-repeating timer and the calculated time interval (`30 - (seconds-of-current-date % 30)`)

  ```
  let currentSeconds = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Second, fromDate: NSDate())
  let initialInterval = NSTimeInterval(30 - currentSeconds % 30)
  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(initialInterval, 
                                          target: self, 
                                        selector: #selector(firstTimerFired(_:)), 
                                        userInfo: nil, 
                                         repeats: false)
  ```
- In the method representing the `selector` reinitialize the timer to repeat with a interval of 30 seconds and a second selector.

  ```
  func firstTimerFired(aTimer : NSTimer) {
     NSLog("firstTimerFired")
     timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(30.0, 
                                             target: self, 
                                           selector: #selector(timerFired(_:)), 
                                           userInfo: nil, 
                                            repeats: true)
  }
  ```
- Using two separate selectors avoids an unnecessary `if` clause to check the *first run*.

  ```
  func timerFired(aTimer : NSTimer) {
    NSLog("timerFired")
  }
  ```

The `NSLog` statements (rather than `print`) print also the current date and time to prove the date.

Answer (score 0):

Solution inspired by the [answer of @vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38590188/2305342) but avoid declaring `NSTimer` and having to scheduled the timer twice and have two selectors

```
let currentSeconds  = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
                                .component(.Second, fromDate:  NSDate())

let initialInterval = NSTimeInterval(30.0 - Double(currentSeconds) % 30.0)

let fireDate =  NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(initialInterval)

let reloadTimer =  NSTimer(fireDate: fireDate,
                                interval: 30.0,
                                target: self,
                                selector: #selector(self.loadData),
                                userInfo: nil,
                                repeats: true)

NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(reloadTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```